# XML arabic-persian text field in adobe flash cs5.5

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to use Arabic & Persian in actionscript 2 in adobe flash cs5.5 and loading texts from XML files.

I have two problems:

1- I can't load Persian without some Persian writing programs and with that programs I can't show Arabic diacritics!

2- I hardly can access my nodes in XML! I dunno it's because I'm using Unicode Characters or something else, but even when I use ANSI characters I have to test the indexes to see which one is going to be the one I want!

can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you can elaborate on your question, maybe with further examples I may be able to help you. Do you have examples of the XML you are having difficulty with?

Comment: It's a brief version of what it's gonna be! I never created the whole XML because I wasn't sure to do it without converting it:    
[download link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/4sap85ig1i2b4l0/data.xml) - and download it to see in right form!

Comment: And I want to do this:             
For example in places which I used <line/>, I want to show arabic attribute text in a dynamically created textfield and make it a movieclip which have the persian attribute text in another frame and a simple code to toggle between frame 1 and frame 2, for each </line> tags and arrange them dynamically [I can arrange them :D I dunno how to do the rest]!